# Lower Mouse Speed

Tags: arch-linux, mouse, kde5

I upgraded my Arch-Linux but now my mouse is too fast.
I googled around and most posts say to lower `Device Accel * Deceleration`  but I don't have such settings:

```
# xinput list-props 8
Device 'Logitech M705':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (277):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (278):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (279):        1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (280):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (281):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (282):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (283):       0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):        0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (284):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (285):     0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (286):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (287):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (288):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (289): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (290): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (291):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (292):        0
    Device Node (265):      "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (266):        1133, 4123
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (293):       <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (294):       1
```

Any ideas how to lower my mouse speed?

I've latest KDE 5.8

Comment: xinput --set-prop 8 277 <desired value> ?  Though that's just acceleration.

Comment: correct, it slows down but using accel and this is not what I want